# debug error when doing memory release

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

The purpose of below code is to correct the false value(-1) to right value, but when i use a dynamic array to record the correct value, the debug error happen. Can someone help me? Thanks.

code.cpp

```
int size = DFS_CODE.size();
int *code = new int[DFS_CODE.size()];

for(int i = 0; i < DFS_CODE.size(); i++) {
    if(DFS_CODE[i].fromlabel == -1)
        DFS_CODE[i].fromlabel = code[DFS_CODE[i].from];
    else if(DFS_CODE[i].tolabel == -1)
        DFS_CODE[i].tolabel = code[DFS_CODE[i].to];

    code[DFS_CODE[i].from] = DFS_CODE[i].fromlabel;
    code[DFS_CODE[i].to] = DFS_CODE[i].tolabel;

    cout << DFS_CODE[i].from << "(" << DFS_CODE[i].fromlabel << ") => "
         << DFS_CODE[i].to << "(" << DFS_CODE[i].tolabel << ")" << endl;
}
delete [] code;
```

debug error

```
debug error!
HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED:after Normal block(#1363) at 0x005745F0. 
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.
```

I found the debug error will also happen when i use malloc. When I take `delete [] code;` or `free(code);`, the debug error will happen. Why? shouldn't i release the memory?

I solve this problem by another way, i use `map` struct to store the right value. Thanks for everyone who help me! Best regards!

```
map <int, int> code;

for(int i = 0; i < DFS_CODE.size(); i++) {
    if(DFS_CODE[i].fromlabel != -1)
        code[DFS_CODE[i].from] = DFS_CODE[i].fromlabel;
    if(DFS_CODE[i].tolabel != -1)
        code[DFS_CODE[i].to] = DFS_CODE[i].tolabel;

    cout << DFS_CODE[i].from << "(" << code[DFS_CODE[i].from] << ") => "
         << DFS_CODE[i].to << "(" << code[DFS_CODE[i].to] << ")" << endl;
}
```

Comment: What are the possible values for `from` and `to` in a `DFS_CODE` of size n?

Comment: I am sure these value is right. The problem happen when i use `delete [] code;`

Comment: The problem happens when you use delete[] or free, because your corrupting the heap previously. At some point you are writing data beyond your "code" array, therefore modifying the next/prev pointers in heap blocks. This has nothing to do with delete[] or free.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But i still can't solve this problem by using dynamic array..., but i solve it by using `map` structure:)

Answer (score 2):

Suspicious to me are these lines

```
code[DFS_CODE[i].from] = DFS_CODE[i].fromlabel;
code[DFS_CODE[i].to] = DFS_CODE[i].tolabel;
```

As you allocate code as follows

```
int *code = new int[DFS_CODE.size()];
```

Make sure you check that .from and .to are < DFS_CODE.size() and >= 0, otherwise you're writing outside of your heap allocated array which can cause heap corruption.

Also, is there a reason you don't replace the array `code` entirely with

```
std::vector<int> code
```

?

Comment: I am very sure the condition you mention does't exist in my code. I found if i take `delete [] code;` out, the error will disappear. But i don't know why. Thanks for your reply:)

Comment: @Mr.mr often the heap corruption detection happens on memory allocation/deallocation (when the heap is actually managed) not on memory access.

Comment: @Mr.mr you should definitely use delete [] code. I'm just saying corruption probably happened before that point and was only detected when the heap was invoked.

Comment: I use another way to solve this problem. Thanks for your help:)

Comment: Can you help me by solving this question? Thank you:) @Doug T.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780955/unexpected-result-of-my-dfs-tree-c

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you allocate your memory for 'code' it is not initialized

```
int *code = new int[DFS_CODE.size()];
```

And the code below uses it...

```
for(int i = 0; i < DFS_CODE.size(); i++) {
    if(DFS_CODE[i].fromlabel == -1)
        DFS_CODE[i].fromlabel = code[DFS_CODE[i].from];
    else if(DFS_CODE[i].tolabel == -1)
        DFS_CODE[i].tolabel = code[DFS_CODE[i].to];
```

This may be causing DFS_CODE to receive undefined values, what is not your problem, but is suspicious...

Comment: Even i initialize `code`, the problem still happen. And the ridiculous thing is that if a take `delete [] code;` out, the problem will be solve..., but i think not releasing the memory is not a good idea, so i solve this problem by using `map` structure. Thanks for your help:)